# inputting a words.txt file python 3

Tags: python, file, loops, input, try-catch

I am stuck why the words.txt is not showing the full grid, below is the tasks i must carry out:

write code to prompt the user for a filename, and attempt to open the file whose name is supplied. If the file cannot be opened the user should be asked to supply another filename; this should continue until a file has been successfully opened.

The file will contain on each line a row from the words grid. Write code to read, in turn, each line of the file, remove the newline character and append the resulting string to a list of strings.After the input is complete the grid should be displayed on the screen.

Below is the code i have carried out so far, any help would be appreciated:

```
file = input("Enter a filename: ")

try:
    a = open(file)
    with open(file) as a:
            x = [line.strip() for line in a]
    print (a)
except IOError as e:
    print ("File Does Not Exist")
```

Comment: You code will not ask for a file name repeatedly because you do not have a while loop. you dont need `a = open(file)` because you are doing the same thing in the next line. Is this really your code?

Comment: Not to worry. Three people have provided ready-to-go solutions to the first part of your homework even though you failed to even ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Always avoid using variable names like `file`, `list` as they are built in python types

```
while True:
    filename = raw_input(' filename: ')
    try:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]
        print lines
        break
    except IOError as e:
        print 'No file found'
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

The below implementation should work:

```
# loop
while(True):
    # don't use name 'file', it's a data type
    the_file = raw_input("Enter a filename: ")
    try:
        with open(the_file) as a:
            x = [line.strip() for line in a]
        # I think you meant to print x, not a
        print(x)
        break
    except IOError as e:
        print("File Does Not Exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop?

```
while True:
    file = input("Enter a filename: ")

    try:
        a = open(file)
        with open(file) as a:
                x = [line.strip() for line in a]
        print (a)
        break
    except IOError:
        pass
```

This will keep asking untill a valid file is provided.